# Php No Error message But Inserted data does is not appearing in table in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

Im Not Sure What the issue could be I am able to store the data from the form in variables display them the input does not throw an error but nothing is in the table. I am using Mamp.

```
<?php 
$server = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$database = 'dikweb_contact';


try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database;", $username, $password);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("Connection failed ". $e->getMessage());
    exit();
}

$name=$_POST['name'];
echo $name;
echo "<br>";
$email=$_POST['email'];
echo $email;
echo "<br>";
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
echo $phone;
echo "<br>";
$message=$_POST['message'];
echo $message;
echo "<br>";
$created_at=date("D, d M Y");
echo $created_at;

$sql = 'INSERT INTO contacts(name, email, phone, message, created_at) VALUES(:name, :email, :phone, :message, :created_at)';

$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute([
    ':name' => $name,
    ':email' => $email,
    ':phone' => $phone,
    ':message' => $message,
    ':created_at' => $created_at
]);

$publisher_id = $conn->lastInsertId();

echo 'The publisher id ' . $publisher_id . ' was inserted';

 ?>
```

Comment: You're not checking for errors.Use `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` so you get an exception if there's an error.

Comment: You didn't check for errors, how can you tell there wasn't any?

Comment: Sorry I removed the print error line in my frustration. I Will try your code its probably

Comment: Barmar where do insert this code This is my first Php Script

Comment: Do you get any output?

Comment: Strange of all is the counter has been increasing every time i try to submit but nothing in phpmyadmin

Comment: output is this Richard William Deemer
richwdgege@gmail.com
63643637
go
Fri, 27 Aug 2021The publisher id 1 was inserted

Comment: im able to post the data from the form and store them as variable I get no error from connection It seems to be an issue in send the data to the table I have another row in the table named id Set to auto incr. Do i have to submit a Null to acount for that.

Comment: No, if you're not specifying the column, the database will take care of it. Interesting that it's returning a 1 for the ID, meaning it seems to be inserted (or else it would return false) but it's not keeping the values

Comment: Im usigng Mamp and accessing through localhost could that be an issue

Comment: No, that shouldn't be an issue. I could see this happening if you were using transactions, but you don't have that mentioned anywhere in your code. Make sure that both the script and PHPMyAdmin are accessing the exact same server/database/table

Comment: When i insert into the data base from the PhPmyadmin Insert tab. I got this output notice that the id is now 2 meaning it accounted for the submission from the script but it still Only showing the data of id two, data from script is not there.                           1 row inserted.
Inserted row id: 2
INSERT INTO `contacts` (`id`, `fname`, `email`, `phone`, `fmessage`, `created_at`) VALUES (NULL, 'richard', 'emai@email.com', 'aEFefF', 'efEF', CURRENT_DATE());  I noticed The fname and fmessage typo

Comment: Even after correcting typo still nothing

Answer (score 0):

Friend You can use this: [all php code available here](https://github.com/musabmahmud/PHP)

```
<?php Class Database{
public $host   = DB_HOST;
public $user   = DB_USER;
public $pass   = DB_PASS;
public $dbname = DB_NAME;

public $link;
public $error;

public function __construct(){
    $this->connectDB();
}

private function connectDB(){
$this->link = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->dbname);
    if(!$this->link){
        $this->error ="Connection fail".$this->link->connect_error;
        return false;
    }
 }}?>
```

Comment: Would be nice to share why original code was incorrect as well.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem seems to have been with the database itself once I dropped it. Once I recreated a new database with the same name and table it worked. Still have no idea what could have caused this.

Answer (score 0):

Your query related code is fine no problem in this but as I am guessing that that in **contacts** table you have created a column "created_at" and it's data type is either DATE or DATETIME.

if it is correct then this field will save only this date format
**Y-m-d H:i:s**

and according to your php code, your date format is D, d M Y. so mysql query is giving you an error.

Please change this line of code

> $created_at=date("D, d M Y");

to

> $created_at=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

Otherwise, you want to save only "D, d M Y" format then please change the datatype of created_at field to VARCHAR